# index of element

Tags: prolog

I'm new to s.o and new to Prolog which is what i am working on, specifically SWI-Prolog.
I am trying to do as the title says, and have gotten it to work on a 1 based list (starting at 1 instead of zero) using some methods that were included in the SWI-library. 
and this is my code:

```
indexof(I,E,L):-
   nth1(I,L,E).
   indexof(-1,_,_).
```

My assignment (yes it's hw -*_*-) is to do this but as a 0 based count
i tried on the last line to add I is I - 1 but i kept getting errors. Is there any other way to get it into a 0 based count?

so for this indexof(A,a,[w,x,y,z,a]). i should get 4 but am getting 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI-Prolog has [nth0/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/3) which is just like [nth1/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3) but the index starts at 0.

To make your original approach work, you need something like:

```
indexof(I,E,L) :-
    nth1(I1,L,E),
    I is I1 - 1.
```

Prolog variables can only be assigned once.  If you tried `I is I - 1`, you're claiming that `I` is itself minus 1.  That's never true, so the predicate fails.  You need to use an intermediate variable, like `I1` in the example above.

Comment: Hey thanks! Having that intermediate variable there makes more sense. I used that technique in 2 of my other methods just didnt think of it here :p So yeah, that is what i was looking for, except the way i have it instead of when the case is false i had it so it returned -1, which although i like your way ALOT better, -1 how im supposed to do it. is there a way i can just swap out the false for a -1? ((again sorry i may sound dumb but i only started learning prolog at the end of last week))

Comment: `(nth1(I1,L,E) -> I is I1 - 1; I = -1)` will return -1 if the element is not found.  The `-> ;` combination is kind of like an if-then-else in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of [nth1/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3) is `nth1(?Index, ?List, ?Elem)`. The `?` means that the argument doesn't have to be instantiated, so Prolog will fill it for you, and that means you don't even have to make a new predicate for the purpose! Here's an example for using the built-in `nth1/3` predicate this way:

```
?- nth1(I, [1,2,3,1,3,4,5], 1).
I = 1 ;
I = 4 ;
false.

?- nth1(I, [1,2,3,1,3,4,5], 2).
I = 2 ;
false.

?- nth1(I, [1,2,3,1,3,4,5], 3).
I = 3 ;
I = 5 ;
false.
```